# PL/SQL SELECT INTO alternative

Tags: select, plsql

I have few SELECT statements that are made by joining multiple tables.
Each select is returning single row but from 10 to 20 fields in that row. What is the easiest way to store that data for later use?

I would like to avoid creating 50 variables and writing select into statements, using cursors and loop for single row is not the smartest idea from what i read around.

Is there a good way to do this?

Stupid example so you can get general idea

```
SELECT t1.field1
, t1.field2
, t1.field3
, t1.field4
, t2.field5
, t2.field6
, t2.field7
, t3.field8
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON something
JOIN table3 t3 ON something
```

Sorry for errors in my english and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view from your select statement. Thereafter can reference a record by using a single variable of type `<viewname>%ROWTYPE`.

Another option would be to wrap the select in an implicit cursor loop:

```
DECLARE
    strvar VARCHAR2(400); -- demo purpose only
BEGIN
    -- ...
    FOR i IN (
        -- ... here goesyour select statement ...
    ) LOOP
       strvar := i.field1 || i.field2; -- ... whatever
    END LOOP;
    -- ...
END;
-- ...
```

Still another option is the declaration of a record type and a record variable:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE tRec IS RECORD (
         field1  table1.field1%TYPE
       , field2  table1.field2%TYPE
       , field3  table1.field3%TYPE
       , field4  table1.field4%TYPE
       , field5  table2.field5%TYPE
       , field6  table2.field6%TYPE
       , field7  table2.field7%TYPE
       , field8  table3.field8%TYPE
   )
   r tRec;
BEGIN
   -- ...
   SELECT --...
     INTO r
     FROM --...
        ;
   -- ...
END;
-- ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't create view, do not have privileges on database. And other solution i have found allready but was told that preformance of using loop for single row is terrible. So i was hoping there is better way to do this

Comment: I cannot seriously comment on the performance issue though by personal experience I'd expect that a 'terrible' performance on a single row tends to be harmless in an environment where large result sets are queried. I have co-developed several db applications with an extensive plsql codebase and that pattern never has been a problem - ymmv.

Comment: You could define a single record variable in plsql which could receive the record. However, you'd have to define the record type with all its components which effectively amounts to the declaration of individual variables for columns. If thats viable,have a look at the code example in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again. For the collection option, i know that one also. And it's better in code understanding (atleast in my opinion) than having 50 variables but still, 4 record types with 10-20 fields, you can call me lazy but i was hoping to avoid that.  If there is really no preformace degradation then cursor/loop option will work for me. Don't know much about preformance but saw big bolded headline **NEVER USE LOOP FOR SINGLE ROW** and preformace was the main reason

Answer (score 1):

Every time you make a select you will have a [cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00602) - there's no escape from that.

Views and explicit cursors are a way to reuse select statements. Which one is better option depends on the case.

[rowtype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99912)-attribute is handy way to create records automatically based on tables/views/cursors. I think this is the closest to your requirement what PL/SQL can offer.

```
create or replace package so51 is
  cursor cursor1 is -- an example single row query
    select
     dual.* -- all table columns included
    ,'Y' as str
    ,rownum as num
    ,sysdate as date_
    from dual
  ;
  function get_data return cursor1%rowtype;
end;
/
show errors

create or replace package body so51 is
  -- function never changes when cursor1 changes
  function get_data return cursor1%rowtype is
    v_data cursor1%rowtype;
  begin
    open cursor1;
    fetch cursor1 into v_data;
    close cursor1;
    return v_data;
  end;
end;
/
show errors

declare
  v_data constant so51.cursor1%rowtype := so51.get_data;
begin
  -- use only the data you need
  dbms_output.put_line('v_data.dummy = ' || v_data.dummy);
  dbms_output.put_line('v_data.str = ' || v_data.str);
  dbms_output.put_line('v_data.num = ' || v_data.num);
  dbms_output.put_line('v_data.date_ = ' || v_data.date_);
end;
/
```

**Example run**

```
SQL> @so51.sql

Package created.

No errors.

Package body created.

No errors.
v_data.dummy = X
v_data.str = Y
v_data.num = 1
v_data.date_ = 2015-11-23 09:42:02

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```